# Lint error on android studio

Tags: android

I have strange lint error, on android studio.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

The super method having the issue, studio says that the error when i hover on it.

> Cannot access android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneyComb

I tired all the stuff to clear the lint error, but it never goes off.

(Invalid cache restart and restart.)

However the app still works, when i build it. no issues anyway.

Anyone faced similar issue like this? and cleared it?

Thanks.

Comment: Add @SupressLint annotation on your activity's `onCreate`

Comment: Hmm, that's not seems to be a nice solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with support library. As soon as i update the app with target version higher. The problem goes away.

Answer (score 3):

Add the dependencies of 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0' to your module.

1. right-click your module;
2. choose the item of Open Module Settings;
3. you will see the dependencies in the right of menu;
4. click the '+' in the bottom,add the library dependency;
5. choose the support-v4(com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0);
6. click OK and you will find everything will be ok.